# Why am I unable to retrieve an item with my function?

Tags: python

I am trying to test my code by typing "Get Notepad". I keep getting:

```
You are in the Dining Room.
You see a Notepad
Enter your move: Get Notepad
You are in the Dining Room.
You see a Notepad
Enter your move:
```

I am not sure what I am missing in order to retrieve the Notepad (or any item for that matter). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my original code:

```
main():
    while True:
        players_room = "Kitchen"
        inventory = {}

        print(
            "Welcome to Barbie’s Dream House! Collect six items to help Barbie defeat the brainwashing Ken by using "
            "the directions North, South, East, and West to move between the rooms. To add to inventory, "
            "type: Get 'item name'. Good luck!")

        rooms = {
            "Kitchen": {"East": "Pool", "South": "Dining Room"},
            "Pool": {"item": "Ken"},
            "Dining Room": {"South": "Living Room", "West": "Bathroom", "East": "Bedroom", "item": "Notepad"},
            "Bathroom": {"East": "Dining Room", "item": "Hairspray"},
            "Living Room": {"North": "Dining Room", "East": "Study", "item": "Laptop"},
            "Study": {"West": "Living Room", "item": "History Book"},
            "Bedroom": {"West": "Dining Room", "North": "Closet", "item": "Cellphone"},
            "Closet": {"South": "Bedroom", "item": "Studious Outfit"}
        }

        while players_room != "exit":
            print(f'You are in the {players_room}.')
            if players_room in inventory:
                print(f'Inventory: {inventory[players_room]}')

            if "item" in rooms[players_room]:
                print(f'You see a {rooms[players_room]["item"]}')

            command = input('Enter your move: ').capitalize()

            if command in rooms[players_room]:
                players_room = rooms[players_room][command]
                if players_room == "Pool":
                    print("Ken brainwashed Barbie - Game over!")
                    break
                elif command.startswith("Get "):
                    item_name = command[4:].strip().lower()
                    if "item" in rooms[players_room] and rooms[players_room]["item"].lower() == item_name:
                        print(f'You have picked up the {rooms[players_room]["item"]}.')
                        inventory[players_room] = rooms[players_room]["item"]
                        rooms[players_room].pop("item")
                        print(f'{inventory[players_room].capitalize()} added to your inventory.')
                    else:
                        print("There's no such item here.")
            elif command == "Exit":
                players_room = "exit"
            else:
                print("Invalid command. Try again.")

        if all("item" not in room for room in rooms.values()):
            print("Congratulations! You have collected all six items! You helped Barbie defeat the brainwashing Ken!")

        play_again = input("Do you want to play again? (yes/no): ").lower()
        if play_again != "yes":
            break

    print('Thanks for playing!')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I have tried asking chatgpt and it is saying it did not see an issue with the code. I honestly am not sure what else to try.

Comment: The `elif command.startsWith("Get ")` block is indented one level too far.

Comment: Do not use ChatGPT for help with programming problems. It is very unlikely to give you a correct, let alone good, solution.

Comment: That did the trick! Thank you! :) Now my game is not ending once the items have been collected.

Answer (score 1):

Your code that checks if the command begins with `Get` is inside the `if command in rooms[players_room]` condition. But `Get Notepad` is not in `rooms[players_room]`. This check should be at the same level, not nested inside.

```
            if command in rooms[players_room]:
                players_room = rooms[players_room][command]
                if players_room == "Pool":
                    print("Ken brainwashed Barbie - Game over!")
                    break
            elif command.startswith("Get "):
                item_name = command[4:].strip().lower()
                if "item" in rooms[players_room] and rooms[players_room]["item"].lower() == item_name:
                    print(f'You have picked up the {rooms[players_room]["item"]}.')
                    inventory[players_room] = rooms[players_room]["item"]
                    rooms[players_room].pop("item")
                    print(f'{inventory[players_room].capitalize()} added to your inventory.')
                else:
                    print("There's no such item here.")
            elif command == "Exit":
                players_room = "exit"
            else:
                print("Invalid command. Try again.")
```